# Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for two-way messaging from JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-chrome, firebase

In other words, I would like to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) from AngularJS to implement real-time chat.
If I understand it properly, this is not possible yet -- please correct me if I am wrong.

Currently two-way messaging (receive and send messages) via FCM can be done in [Android SDK, iOS SDK, in Chrome Apps and Chrome plugins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). 
However JS frameworks (which fall under "Websites in Chrome") can benefit only from one-way push notifications, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client):

> Websites in Chrome can implement push messaging through service workers and web app manifests following the Webpush standard.

Comment: Peter where you able to successfully implement FCM on a webapp? I have been struggling with it I followed the codelabs example of push notification in webapp example and i'm using Server key from firebase console and i keep getting 401 error when i try to http POST

Comment: Jasan, I did not used FCM at the end and successfully used Firebase Realtime Database  as suggested Ian.

Answer (score 3):

FCM is not a good solution for two way chat on the web - exactly as you say, it is focused on push messaging.

However, the Firebase Realtime Database is a great tool for this kind of app! If you take a look at the [Firebase Friendly Chat Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0) it leads you through building a chat client.